# Distinct Array values in z3 SMT solver

Tags: z3, smt

I tried around a some time to get a rather simple requirement done:
I declared a new datatype

`(declare-datatypes () ((A (mk_A (key Int) (var1 Int) (var2 Int)))))`

where `key` should act like a primary key in a database, i.e., each different instance of `A` should have a different `key` value. 
The container of the different instances (functions) looks like the following:

`(declare-const A_instances (Array Int A))`

So far so good. I tried to create an assertion, such that all instances in `A_instances` have a different `key` field. Thus, for each index `i` in A_instances `(key (select A_instances i))` should be distinct. However it returns `unknown`.

Someone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is

```
(declare-datatypes () ((A (mk_A (key Int) (var1 Int) (var2 Int)))))
(declare-const A_instances (Array Int A))
(declare-fun j () Int)
(assert (forall ((i Int))  (implies (distinct i j) 
                           (distinct (key (select A_instances i))  
                                     (key (select A_instances j)))        )   ))
(check-sat)
```

and the corresponding output is

```
sat
```